# find which li was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, html-lists

suppose i have 3 li. what i want to do is when i click any li then i want to know which li was clicked and add an event according to it. how do i do it with jquery, any help or suggestions please

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Get clicked element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758890/javascript-get-clicked-element)

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, within an event handler the **this** keyword refers to the element which triggered the event.

```
$('li').click(function() {
  alert($(this).text()); // read out the text of the list item that was clicked
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will automatically capture the clicked element that you specify in the wrapped set:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  alert('I was clicked, my text is: ' + $(this).text());
});
```

[See the example here.](http://jsbin.com/owaku3)

You need to provide your html markup for exact what you need.

**More Readings:**

- [jQuery's this: demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)