# JavaScript: Get clicked element

Tags: javascript

I need to get clicked element in function getClickedElement. How can I do this?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function getClickedElement () {
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript:alert(getClickedElement())" id="test">click me!!!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I can set only href attribute.
I can not set onclick event because this elements is generated by third party lib.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you told why you need this, what you want to do. Maybe there are other ways.

Comment: What is the third party library ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't get the clicked element in a `javascript:` URL. The event has already finished, so there's no `event.target` (or `window.event.srcElement` for IE), and `javascript:` links are not invoked with `this` set (so you get `window`).

Of course if you *know* the link in question is `id="test"` you can do `document.getElementById('test')`, but I suspect that's rather missing the point of what you want to do.

> I can set only href attribute. I can not set onclick event because this elements is generated by third party lib.

Fix or drop the lib. `javascript:` URLs are utter horrors that should **never** be used.

Can you add a `<script>` elsewhere in the page? If so you can inject a `click` event handler onto the element(s) without needing any extra markup. eg.:

```
for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;)
    if (document.links[i] is one of the links you want to target)
        document.links[i].onclick= someHandlerFunction;

function someHandlerFunction() {
    alert(this);
    return false;
}
```

Indeed, assigning from JS (with `on...` or via `addEventListener` with `attachEvent` fallback for IE) is the best-practice way of adding event handlers anyway.

Comment: Although this answer was helpful, I'm not sure what the answerer means by 'document.links[i] is one of the links you want to target'. How would somebody write this comparison out in the actual code? Why didn't the author of this answer just write out the actual code instead of randomly jumping into layman's terms?

Answer (score 8):

the following statckoverflow question gives a way to detect clicked element
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document)

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
});
```

Comment: There is little interest in answering a very old question that was already answered before. Furthermore, your answer doesn't help since the Original Poster (OP) did not use jquery.

Comment: This was actually exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The vanilla version of this is `document.addEventListener("click", callback)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: The use of jQuery is extremely unnecessary

Comment: Some people complain that this does not help. It actually did help me! Thanks! I used the following code: ```function handle(event) { console.log("Clicked on tag:", event.target.textContent); setSelection(document.getElementById(__pubs_dd_tags_id), event.target.textContent); populatePublicationList(); }``` and then set ```element.onclick = handle;```.

Comment: Helped me too. Wish other people would wind their necks in sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:alert(getClickedElement('test'))" id="test">click me!!!</a>

<script>
function getClickedElement (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
</script>
```

or, if you can't predict the ID, you can use Javascript to attach events after page is loaded. Look at jQuery. Use something like `$('a').click(function() {return this.id; });`

Comment: I don't know element ID. It is generated by third party lib. I can set only href value.

Comment: you can use Javascript then to attach events after page is loaded. Look at jQuery. Use something like `$('a').click(function() {return this.id; });`

Answer (score 1):

To detect clicks on any element on the whole page, you can set the `"click"` event of the document, and that should activate no matter which element you click.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("You clicked this element:", e.target);
});
```

For right-clicking, the event is `"contextmenu"`.

Even if the target element calls `e.preventDefault()`, this still detects the click. The only exception is if the the target or one of its parent calls `e.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score -1):

you can pass this as a parameter and you can then know what is the element you are looking for.
for example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function getClickedElement ($this) {

    }
  </script>
</head>enter code here
<body>
  <a href="javascript:alert(getClickedElement(this))" id="test">click me!!!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

hope it will help you, it helped me :)