# Web Browser control in C++: Detecting mouse click on specific button

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

My C++ application is using a web browser (IE) control. I need to detect when the user clicks a button on a specific web page (using the element ID of that button).
How can I do this? I already have an event sink implemented, but I do not know how to catch mouse click on DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

The event you are looking for is probably related to:

[onclick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536913%28v=vs.85%29)

But whether this is accessible from the MS IE API from C++ via EventSinks, I don't know.

### Other Round-About Way to Get Click Information to Your C++ Code

I am not an expert on it, but companies like UserZoom, analyze the information by inserting Javascript via a plug-in to the web browser.  Here is a quote from their FAQ of how they collect the click-streams:

[UserZoom FAQ](http://www.userzoom.com/faq)

> Data Collection & Tracking
>
> What type of information is UserZoom
>   capable of tracking during the tasks?
>
> With the plug-in version or non plug-in with JavaScript tracking code,
>   UserZoom can track participants’ navigation paths as well as where
>   participants have clicked on pages throughout the tasks (heatmaps).
>   With the non plug-in version, navigation paths and participant clicks
>   cannot be captured.

Now with this knowledge, go find a javascript library that can get the clicks and the document object model info.

[Google Search: "how to get where the user clicked element in javascript"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20how%20to%20get%20where%20the%20user%20clicked)

[How to get the target element when clicked?](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-12729.html)

[StackOverflow: JavaScript: Get clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758890/javascript-get-clicked-element)

Then you need to insert that bit of javascript into the webpages into the browser the user is using.

Adding Javascript with an add-on/extension/plugin in Firefox and Chrome is relatively easy, I've heard, but for IE, I think you have your work cut out for you to create the add-on in IE.  After much searching I found this:

[Inject HTML and JavaScript into an existing page with BHO using MS Visual Studio 2010 and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w)

And lastly, get that information out of the javascript and into your code using JSON or AJAX and setting up a local webserver to receive it:

[Google Search: receive ajax c++](https://www.google.com/search?q=receive%20ajax%20c%2b%2b)

[Jquery Ajax Calling Functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224827/Jquery-Ajax-Calling-functions)

[AJAX and the C++ Programmer](http://suite101.com/article/ajax-and-the-c-programmer-a65762)

Hopefully that information gives you a starting point.  Good luck.