# How to get the element clicked (for the whole document)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to get the current element (whatever element that is) in an HTML document that I clicked. I am using:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

But very strangely, I get the text of the whole(!) document, not the clicked element.

How to get only the element I clicked on?

#### Example

```
<body>
    <div class="myclass">test</div>
    <p>asdfasfasf</p>
</body>
```

If I click on the "test" text, I would like to be able to read the attribute with `$(this).attr("myclass"`) in jQuery.

Comment: The handler function executes in the scope of the element it is added to, here the document. You will need to get the `target` property of the event object.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You need to use the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) which is the element which originally triggered the event. The `this` in your example code refers to `document`.

In jQuery, that's...

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
});
```

Without jQuery...

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText;   
}, false);
```

Also, ensure if you need to support < IE9 that you use `attachEvent()` instead of `addEventListener()`.

Comment: I found that the element that was return was slightly different somehow, so I couldnt do `if(event.target === myjQueryDivElement)` I had to do: `if(event.target.hasClass('mydivclass'))` where mydivclass was a class that my element had.

Comment: I have been looking for a work around in Safari for 3 days and I finally stumbled upon this post. You guys rock thanks

Comment: @alex hey, should it be `|| target.innerText`?

Answer (score 81):

`event.target` to get the `element`

```
window.onclick = e => {
    console.log(e.target);  // to get the element
    console.log(e.target.tagName);  // to get the element tag name alone
}
```

to get the text from clicked element

```
window.onclick = e => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
}
```

Comment: I came here for the right click, so I tried RightClick, but it did not work.

Comment: For right click - instead of onclick add oncontextmenu

Comment: e.target returns the child click element. If a button has a child, you will not get the button, but the clicked child.

Comment: If not, only the body tag will return in most cases

Answer (score 36):

use the following inside the body tag

```
<body onclick="theFunction(event)">
```

then use in javascript the following function to get the ID

```
<script>
function theFunction(e)
{ alert(e.target.id);}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can find the target element in [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    console.log($(event.target).text());
});
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 4):

Use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). `delegate` takes advantage of the event bubbling by letting one element listen for, and handle, events on child elements. `target` is the jQ-normalized property of the `event` object representing the object from which the event originated.

```
$(document).delegate('*', 'click', function (event) {
    // event.target is the element
    // $(event.target).text() gets its text
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xXTbP/

Comment: Should be mentioned in this day and age that `on()` should be recommended over `delegate()`. Also, `document` is probably the only exception to not use `delegate()`/`on()` as they are bubbling to the highest point of handling anyway.

Comment: Good call. We've not upgraded to the most recent jQuery at my day job, so `on` slips my mind.

Comment: @alex, since the events are bubbling anyway, and since the handler has to run regardless, it's not really an exception is it? It's just not that different is all. I guess `delegate` does have the filtering overhead to consider, though...

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is really old but, to get the contents of an element in reference to its ID, this is what I would do:

```js
window.onclick = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.id, ' -->', e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the esiest way to get clicked element in javascript.

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target));
```

Comment: concise solution!

Answer (score 1):

pass "this" as argument when you call the function:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="click_here(this);">clicked</span>
<script>
function click_here(elmnt){
alert($(elmnt).text());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).text());
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution that uses a jQuery selector so you can easily target tags of any class, ID, type etc.

```
jQuery('div').on('click', function(){
    var node = jQuery(this).get(0);
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents( node );
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange( range );
});
```