# Click on <tr>, but only if clicked <td> is not an <a>

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with structure like this :

```
 <table>
 <tr id="ui-id-7" onclick="editThis();">
 <td>100</td>
 <td>Test</td>
 <td class="noEdit"><a href="www.mysite.com" target="_blank"><img src="www.mysite.com/test.jpg"></a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

What I need : the entire `<tr>` is clickable and calls the `editThis()` method, UNLESS if the user clicks on the `<td>` that has the link element (in case, the one with `noEdit` class).

In the code above, clicking on ANY `<td>` (or the `<tr>`) will call the `editThis()` method. I know I could write the call for each `<td>` instead of the `<tr>`, but this would be a lot of writing...

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('#ui-id-7 td.noEdit').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event

Comment: @delphirules and that's exactly what the answer does. If you also want to prevent the page to navigate to the `href` value than add `e.preventDefault();` too.

Comment: Why is this only works on the <td> in the first row?