# How to get the text content of a DOM generated by a click of another element on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a very specific website in mind in which the words on the webpage are clickable and upon clicking it generates a new DOM element.

I'm trying to create a chrome extension in which when the user clicks on a webpage, the click triggers a function that returns the element generated by it's id.

right now this is what I have

```
<script>
  document.onclick = function(myFunction)

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsById("v0")
    return x 
  }
</script>
```

I'm unable to see anything logged on console when I load the extension.

is document.onclick the right method to use? and should I use getElementByClassName or getElementById?

Comment: Where do you log to console? I can't see anything like this.

Comment: to sart with change to `document.onclick = myFunction()`

Comment: do I have to add console.log(x)?

Comment: @SimonH — Why? It is only useful to assign a function to `onclick` and the return value of `myFunction` isn't one.

Comment: Also, is document.onclick the proper way to track clicks on a global level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the element clicked (for the whole document)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document)

Comment: Use event.target.id on Event handler of texts

Comment: @WesFoster I'm not trying to get the element clicked on, but rather the new DOM element generated due to the a click on an document element.

Answer (score 0):

`document.onclick = function(myFunction)` is an error. You are trying to call a function called *function* and assign its return value to `document.onclick` — but *function* is a keyword and can't be a function name.

To assign `myFunction` as an onclick handler, then just assign that function:

```
document.onclick = myFunction;
```

That won't do you much good though: `myFunction` gets an element by its id and returns it, but the return value of a click event handler isn't used for anything (other than preventing the default behaviour of the click).

You would need to rewrite `myFunction` so it did something useful with the element.

Comment: I want myFunction to return the string content of the element v0, how do I do that?

Comment: @Baleno — Return it to where? The return function of an event handler function should be `true` or `false`, not a string (although a sting will be treated as `true` or `false` depending on its content).

Comment: I guess I would want the data to be stored in an object. the element is question is a word and it's definition.

Comment: I would create a new object with the the word and it's definition as a key-value pair. And stored in the local storage of the browser

Comment: OK, so forget about returning a value and use the local storage API.

Comment: Actually, I would want to save that data on firebase, using the firebase API

Comment: Fine, then use the firebase API. Just don't try to return the value because it doesn't make sense to return a value from an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You want to bind a click action to the document. After the click happens, you want the target of the event to be captured.

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
});
```

Pure JS:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
}, false);
```

From there, you can do whatever you want with it. For example:

```
var id = target.attr('id');  // jQuery
var id = target.id;          // Javascript
```

Comment: what would  `var target = $(event.target)` do? 
set a variable called target to the the element clicked on?