# Javascript - style elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, styles

I have an array of images and I want to style those images with a border whenever they are clicked on. I can get one image to style using an index number, but can't seem to get the function to run on each image whenever it's clicked on. I get a "cannot set property of 'border' of undefined
at HTMLImageElement.picStyle".

HTML:

```
<div id="pic-container">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog1.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog2.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog3.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog4.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog5.jpg">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var dogPics = document.getElementsByClassName('dogImg');

function picStyle() {
   dogPics.style.border = "1px solid black";
   }


for (var i = 0; i < dogPics.length; i++) {
   dogPics[i].addEventListener('click' , picStyle ) ; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the element clicked (for the whole document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `dogPics.style.border` use `this.style.border`.

```js
var dogPics = document.getElementsByClassName('dogImg');

function picStyle() {
   this.style.border = "1px solid black";
   }


for (var i = 0; i < dogPics.length; i++) {
   dogPics[i].addEventListener('click' , picStyle ) ; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pic-container">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog1.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog2.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog3.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog4.jpg">
    <img class ="dogImg" src="img/dog5.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: @1024 glad it helped.