# adding event listener for multiple elements and detecting which element is triggering the event - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I have added `click` event listener on multiple elements in `jQuery` which works fine:

```
$('#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4').on('click', function(){
  // do something with the clicked element
});
```

Now I would like to find out which element is being clicked. How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the element clicked (for the whole document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `this` or check the *target* property of the passing *event* of the event handler function:

Using [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```js
$('#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4').on('click', function(event){
    console.log('The id of the clicked button is: ' +this.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="element1">Button1</button>
<button id="element2">Button2</button>
<button id="element3">Button3</button>
<button id="element4">Button4</button>
```

Using [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
$('#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4').on('click', function(event){
    console.log('The id of the clicked button is: ' +event.target.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="element1">Button1</button>
<button id="element2">Button2</button>
<button id="element3">Button3</button>
<button id="element4">Button4</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by following

```
$('#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4').on('click', function(){
       var ID = $(this).attr('id'); 
       alert('you clicked on #' +ID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with event.target

```
$('#element1, #element2, #element3, #element4').on('click', function(event){
    console.log(event.target)
});
```

Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) for more understanding