# Chrome extension not detecting input field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first Chrome extension and the code just seems to not be working. Basically for now, I want the extension to be able to identify a click on an input field and give an alert. I think the extension is not recognizing the click. I've tried multiple things, but here's the most recent code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Pi",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Pi works!",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "pie.png"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["contentScript.js"]
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert('HELLO WORLD!!');
});
```

**contentScript.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('input').addEventListener("click", function (){
  alert("Hi");
});

});
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I'd like the extension to always keep running in the background and detect whenever a user clicks on an input field on any website. Upon the clicking inside the input field (bringing it to focus), I want it to give an alert.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){` You actually don't need it. The chrome Browser will decide when to run content script based on `run_at` settings in the `manifest.json` default is `document_idle`. [See more here.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time)

GodsArchitect's example is correct for detecting the click event of `INPUT` tags. However, you may need to consider `onFocus` event on `INPUT` tags in case if users use keyboard TAB key to focus into the input field.

```
const inputTags = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))

inputTags.forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
    alert("Hi...")
  }, false)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does the job.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
        alert('You clicked an Input!');
    }
}, false);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012576/10383955