# JS get the clicked element with event.target

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use JavaScript to get a clicked element's information.
Below is my code.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // how to get the clicked p tag here?
  // this?
  // event.target.currentTarget?
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text 1</p>
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

How can I use `this` to get the element's information?

Comment: What's the problem? Did you try `event.target`?

Comment: If you really want to only get the p-tags, I'd suggest not to add the eventlistener to the parent but to the p tags directly. Otherwise you could also receive child elements like <strong> or <a> tags as targets.

Comment: `event.target` will give you the element that was clicked on while `event.currentTarget` will give you the element the event was originally bound to (i.e. the div).

Comment: @JuanMendes no I didn't lol, thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the element clicked (for the whole document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`e.target` should give you the exact element that was clicked to generate the event.

`e.currentTarget` will give you the element
that the event is at when the function
was called (after bubbling up from the `e.target`)

```
div.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
console.log(e.target) // the p that was clicked
console.log(e.currentTarget) // this div
})
```

Comment: What if the currentTarget is null? I have simillar situatuation with button, which has an event attached and nested span. After click at span I've get `target=span` and `currentTarget=null`.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment `event.target` should be fine. But you should be careful if you really only want the p-tags. If you use a-tags or other child elements in the wrapping div you could potentially also receive other tags.

I'd suggest to actually add the event listener to the p-tags directly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to attach the event listener to each of the `p` elements in case you have other children elements nested within the `p` element itself.

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("div > p");

for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i += 1) {
  paragraphs[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
  });
}
```

Comment: As long as they're all under the `div` you could catch the event in the `div` and then use `event.target` to get the p tag that was clicked.

Comment: Yes, if there are no other descendants of the `p` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `event.target` you should get the specific `p` tag that you clicked.

However, if you really want to use `this`, you're better off attaching the onclick event handler to the p tags themselves rather than the parent.

Like so.

```
let ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p')

for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i){
    ps[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        // how to get the clicked p tag here?
        alert(this.innerText) //or whatever action you want to do with `this`
   })
}
```