# Getting the parent of button without ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling to get the parent of button when it is clicked. This is my HTML structure:

`<p><button class="remove">x</button> Hamlet<input value="5"></p>`

I don't want to use the ID in button because I have many of the same buttons. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: The problem is solved in JS, please show the JS code related to the event handler of the button.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054548/js-get-the-clicked-element-with-event-target) to get the button, then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element) to get its parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe consider adding a universal click event to all buttons.

```js
const onClickButton = function () {
  // The parent element
  const parent = this.parentElement;
  parent.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};

[...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', onClickButton));
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="remove">x</button>
  Hamlet1
  <input value="5">
</p>

<p>
  <button class="remove">x</button>
  Hamlet2
  <input value="5">
</p>

<p>
  <button class="remove">x</button>
  Hamlet3
  <input value="5">
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this? Note I delegate from a container

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) tgt.closest("p").remove();
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p><button class="remove">x</button> Hamlet<input value="1"></p>
  <p><button class="remove">x</button> Ophelia<input value="2"></p>
  <p><button class="remove">x</button> Polonius<input value="3"></p>
</div>
```

For browser that doe not like `closest` you can use `tgt.parentElement.remove()`