# Input date calendar does not open

Tags: javascript, html

I compose a part of the code of my project here to report the problem I am facing. I need to keep the js function to work the links that I put in the top bar.

```js
$(function () {

    function setFlatTheme() {
        $("body").toggleClass("flat-theme");
        $("#rad-color-opts").toggleClass("hide");
        $(".rad-chk-pin input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
    }
    
    setFlatTheme();
    
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $item = $(".rad-dropmenu-item");
        if ($item.hasClass("active")) {
            $item.removeClass("active");
        }
    });

    $("li.rad-dropdown > a.rad-menu-item").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".rad-dropmenu-item").removeClass("active");
        $(this).next(".rad-dropmenu-item").toggleClass("active");
    });

});
```

```css
.links > li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rad-dropmenu-item.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: flipInX 1s ease;
}

.rad-notification-body {
  color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.rad-logo-container {
  width: 225px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.rad-menu-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #89949B;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rad-dropmenu-item {
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: 45px;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  border-top: 5px solid #515d6e;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
}

.rad-chk-pin span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: crimson;
  border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
}
.rad-chk-pin span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.rad-chk-pin input {
  display: none;
}
.rad-chk-pin input:checked + span {
  background: #23AE89;
}
.rad-chk-pin input:checked + span:after {
  left: 19px;
}

.rad-color-swatch {
  display: table;
  width: 90px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.rad-color-swatch .colors {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rad-color-swatch .colors input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.rad-color-swatch .colors:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.rad-color-swatch .colors:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min {
  width: 65px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {

  .rad-navigation {
    height: 100px;
  }

  .rad-logo-container.rad-nav-min + .rad-logo-hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .rad-logo-container {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  }

  .rad-top-nav-container {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
  }
  
  .rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min {
    transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
  }

}

.flat-theme .rad-navigation .rad-top-nav-container .links > li > a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.rad-bg-purple {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.rad-bg-twitter {
  background: #55acee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.3/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body>
  
  <section>
    <header>
        <nav class="rad-navigation">
            <div class="rad-logo-container rad-nav-min">
                <a href="#" class="rad-logo"><span class="letra">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx </span></a>
                <a href="#" class="rad-toggle-btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-bars acertobar"></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="rad-logo-hidden">xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx</a>
            <div class="rad-top-nav-container">
                <ul class="pull-right links">
                    <li class="rad-dropdown no-color">
                        <a class="rad-menu-item" id="verificar" href="#"><img class="rad-list-img sm-img acerto" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['image'] ?>" alt="me" /></a>
                        <ul class="rad-dropmenu-item sm-menu">
                            <li class="rad-notification-item">
                                <a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="https://gestao.centropadreangelo.pt"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Perfil</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="rad-notification-item">
                               <a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rad-dropdown"><a id="verificar" class="rad-menu-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                        <ul class="rad-dropmenu-item rad-settings">
                            <li class="rad-dropmenu-header"><a href="#">Definições</a></li>
                            <li class="rad-notification-item text-left">
                                <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <label class="rad-chk-pin pull-right">
                                        <input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rad-notification-body">
                                    <div class="lg-text">Mudar para tema plano</div>
                                    <div class="sm-text">Flattify it</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li id="rad-color-opts" class="rad-notification-item text-left hide">
                                <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i></div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <div class="rad-color-swatch">
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-crimson rad-option-selected">
                                            <input type="radio" checked name="color" value="crimson" />
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-teal">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="teal" />
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-purple">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple">
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-orange">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" />
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-twitter">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="twitter" />
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rad-notification-body">
                                    <div class="lg-text">Escolha uma cor</div>
                                    <div class="sm-text">Torne-o colorido</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                    
                    </li>   
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right links">
                    <li>
                        <span class="letra1">xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</section>
<aside>
    <nav class="rad-sidebar rad-nav-min">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt" class="inbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-home acerto"><span class="icon-bg"></span></i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">HOME</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/xxx.php" class="inbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-user">
                        <span class="icon-bg"></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">INSCRIÇÃO</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
<main>

<form class="steps" id="inscricao" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="">



        
          <label for="validade" Style="margin-top: 10%;">Data de Validade </label>

          <input id="validade" name="validade" type="date" >

  
 
</form>
</main>
</body>
```

But when you put this function, you stop opening the calendar in the input with the date type. If you remove the function, the calendar of the input already works. But when I remove the function, I’m unable to close the links on the top bar.
Can you help solve this problem?

Comment: Check what is being clicked before preventing default. Use e.target/e.currentTarget to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the element clicked (for the whole document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey It doesn't keep my problem. I will improve the question to put the most complete code

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I updated the question with both situations. As the question is, the input does not open the calendar, but the links in the bar at the top open and close. If I remove the function I talked about initially or change it as suggested in the answer given, the calendar works but I can't close the links on the top bar

Comment: Right, as I said in my first comment, you need to check what was clicked. If the thing that was clicked was a menu item, do what needs to be done there (open, close, whatever), and prevent it from going further. If it's a calendar control, do what needs to be done there, and prevent it from going further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the `preventDefault()` inside the if condition. So that the click default action is prevented only if the menu is opened. As per your current code, what happens is that It is capturing all click events on document and then preventing the event trigger always. So the datepicker is not able to catch the click event on calender and the calender never opens. With the following modification, now the click event will only get prevented when the menu is open.

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
      var $item = $(".rad-dropmenu-item");
      if ($item.hasClass("active")) {
          $item.removeClass("active");
          e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  
  <section>
    <header>
        <nav class="rad-navigation">
            <div class="rad-logo-container rad-nav-min">
                <a href="#" class="rad-logo"><span class="letra">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx </span></a>
                <a href="#" class="rad-toggle-btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-bars acertobar"></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="rad-logo-hidden">xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx</a>
            <div class="rad-top-nav-container">
                <ul class="pull-right links">
                    <li class="rad-dropdown no-color">
                        <a class="rad-menu-item" id="verificar" href="#"><img class="rad-list-img sm-img acerto" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['image'] ?>" alt="me" /></a>
                        <ul class="rad-dropmenu-item sm-menu">
                            <li class="rad-notification-item">
                                <a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="https://gestao.centropadreangelo.pt"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Perfil</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="rad-notification-item">
                               <a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rad-dropdown"><a id="verificar" class="rad-menu-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                        <ul class="rad-dropmenu-item rad-settings">
                            <li class="rad-dropmenu-header"><a href="#">Definições</a></li>
                            <li class="rad-notification-item text-left">
                                <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <label class="rad-chk-pin pull-right">
                                        <input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rad-notification-body">
                                    <div class="lg-text">Mudar para tema plano</div>
                                    <div class="sm-text">Flattify it</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li id="rad-color-opts" class="rad-notification-item text-left hide">
                                <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i></div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <div class="rad-color-swatch">
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-crimson rad-option-selected">
                                            <input type="radio" checked name="color" value="crimson" />
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-teal">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="teal" />
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-purple">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple">
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-orange">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" />
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="colors rad-bg-twitter">
                                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="twitter" />
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rad-notification-body">
                                    <div class="lg-text">Escolha uma cor</div>
                                    <div class="sm-text">Torne-o colorido</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                    
                    </li>   
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right links">
                    <li>
                        <span class="letra1">xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</section>
<aside>
    <nav class="rad-sidebar rad-nav-min">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt" class="inbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-home acerto"><span class="icon-bg"></span></i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">HOME</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/xxx.php" class="inbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-user">
                        <span class="icon-bg"></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">INSCRIÇÃO</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="inbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-power-off">
                        <span class="icon-bg"></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">Terminar Sessão</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
<main>


<div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="validade">Data de Validade <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>

          <input id="validade" name="validade" required="required" type="date" value="<?php echo $validade; ?>" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>    
        
</main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //<-- THIS HERE
```

When you click **anywhere** on the document, that click will be caught and the default action (like opening the date picker) will be prevented.

I suggest that instead of calling the `.on()` function on the entire document you limit it only to the part where your links are i.e.

```
$(".rad-navigation").on("click", ....
```

(this selects the .rad-navigation class)

Comment: But by putting it the way you suggested, then when I open the links on the top bar as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Jpi.png), I can't close them that way. But that way the calendar already works. Is there a way to work the calendar and be able to close the links? Everything depends on this function to work

Comment: @Pinto An alternative would be to check if you clicked on the date picker before `e.preventDefault();` and if you did, ignore the click