# jQuery - Get the Class of the child element clicked

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="one">ONE</div>
  <div class="two">TWO</div>
  <div class="three">THREE</div>
</div>
```

If I have a click function as follows, how can I get the class name of the element that is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '#wrapper', function (event) {
    // get class name
});
```

So if I was to click `TWO`, it would return `two`

--

Just to add, the click handler would have to remain as `#wrapper`, so essentially I need to get the child element that was clicked...

Comment: See the answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012537/how-to-get-the-element-clicked-for-the-whole-document). Basically: `event.target.className` or if you want more jQuery, `$(event.target).attr("class")`. Or if you may have a `span` inside the `div` but you want to use `$(event.target).closest("div").attr("class")` (the DOM also has a `closest` method now). Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Small Correction required.
Trigger click event on child div.

```
$(document).on('click', '#wrapper div', function (event) {
   var classname =$(this).attr('class');
   alert(classname);

});
```

Comment: But what if I have to have the click function happening on the click event of `#wrapper` ?

Comment: no, you will not get the child's class name as you are clicking and getting  event on #wrapper.

Comment: @AjayGupta - It's entirely possible to get the class of the inner element when handling it on the wrapper. But the question is an **obvious**, often-repeated duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I am not sure how? Can you please provide some example.

Comment: @AjayGupta - See the linked question's answers, and my comment on the question. In short: `event.target`.

Comment: oh. @nsilva,  you can try.